A class of directed graph, when their minimal polynomial of the adjacency matrix matches the characteristic polynomial
We consider an unweighted directed simple graph, $G$, with a Hamiltonian cycle.

Q. Assume that the adjacency matrix of $G$ is non-singular.  Do the characteristic and minimal polynomials of the adjacency matrix of $G$ coincide?

